# sharekit facebook not showing login page

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

hi I am trying to integrate fb image sharing on my app. So I decided to go with sharekit. I downloaded the latest version. I've created a facebook app and added appkey and secretkey into `shkconfig.h` as guided by the sharekit document. The issues no I'm facing is when I click on facebook share, fbshare screen appears and I can see the  activity monitor and after sometime nothing happens and the title of the screen disappears. When I remove the app key and secret key I see the login page.What am I doing wrong or do I have to configure something else . I have added the screenshot of what's happening.

[image: screen shot when fb share is clicked]

[image]

Comment: @Robuust sorry I have added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow ALL the steps in their tutorial.

The ones that cross my mind in your case are :

1) Adding the appKey and secretKey to info.plist

2) Adding these methods in your delegate class:

- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;

I followed their steps one by one and it worked like a charm. 
Also , make sure you used [this](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) one . There's an old one too , but it's not supported.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

EDIT:

That's the old version as far as I know. You should get the one that I linked to above and follow the instructions in the [wiki section here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) . Before doing that please remove the old version of ShareKit that you installed. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hey thanks. I downloaded this http://getsharekit.com/install/ and followed this tutorial.can send the link of the tutorial u followed

Comment: thanks i followed your answer was able to configure sharekit and was able to post image from exampleapp provided in sharekit using my myfbappid. But now when i run the same on my app it crashes showing exc_bad_access in shkconfiguration and sometimes if does not it shows fblogin page and says could not login.

Comment: You should google the error that you get and maybe post it here too